# What to do if a special case of a theorem is published

Tags: publications, plagiarism, editors

I published  a paper in a reputable journal in 2021 December. I had proved a conjecture.
Today I discovered that another author published a special case of the conjecture and published it, in another journal, in 2023.

I think it is wrong on the journal's part. Why did the Editors publish the paper when they can see that it is a special case of my paper?

Shall I write to the journal and ask them to remove the paper from their website?
Or do I file a case of plagiarism against the author?

If someone can kindly help, I will be grateful.

Comment: Did the author of the other paper cite your paper?

Comment: Is the proof your proof adapted to the special case, or different?

Comment: @Nobody; no they did not

Comment: @erstwhileeditor; somewhat different

Comment: Do you have strong evidence that the author of the 2023 article was aware of your article? And was the 2023 article also published in a reputable journal?

Comment: Out of curiosity: what would happen if it turns out that neither the authors nor the reviewers of the new paper were aware of OP's paper, and that there is indeed substantial overlap in the content (such that in light of the existence of the earlier paper, the new one cannot be considered original).  does the new paper get retracted?

Comment: @Aqualone It will likely happen nothing. Lack of novelty is not a reason for retraction, which typically is reserved for cases of scientific misconduct or for egregiously wrong results.

Comment: There are numerous cases in physics and mathematics of different authors publishing similar results, often years apart ... and we often find that the result is credited with a double-surname title as in "the Smith-Jones theorem". So your suggestion that "the new one cannot be considered original" is not, I think, correct. But that hinges on whether you take "original" to mean "first ever published", "first ever published in this language", or "something created without knowledge of, or reference to, the other".

Comment: Related: [How to get priority acknowledged, when a paper in mathematics is a special case of your own paper, but it does not cite your work?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/85330/17254)

Comment: @Aqualone Before the internet this was really common, because it was difficult to get information to everyone/to find work of others, especially if you were coming at a problem from different directions. Now it's common because there is just *so much* out there that it's easy to get lost in the flood of information.

Comment: @CrimsonDark By "original" I mean "worthy of publication", whatever that may mean  .  Basically, my question was about the situation when: paper A is published. years later, a similar paper B appears, but it makes to publication only because neither the authors nor reviewers of B were aware of A.

Comment: what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: My immediate thought is that if somebody independently proved a similar result, they're likely in/adjacent to a field you're going to continue being involved in. Becoming enemies with them doesn't serve you at all. It feels like any action you take should be weighed in light of the question "is it really worth burning this potential bridge"?

Comment: Are special cases of more general theorums not still worth knowing about?

Comment: I remember reading a paper whose most important contribution was "We notice that in our context, theorem 1 from paper X can be reworded as...". So basically they just wrote a particular case of a previously-published theorem. Just noticing that this theorem from an abstract math paper applied to their domain was already huge.

Comment: Put yourself in their shoes. What if someone else had provided the proof and you were unaware of it? Would you retract? Would you cite them? Would you voluntarily submit to the consequences of plagiarism, even if it was clearly not involved?

Comment: You haven't said whether it would be obvious to anyone that their conjecture was a special case of yours, or whether demonstrating that this is the case is in itself a significant intellectual achievement.

Answer (score 67, accepted):

With the amount of papers that are published nowadays, it’s not rare that a result gets overlooked, whether your are an author, reviewer or editor.

If the proof published in the new paper is somewhat different from yours, it can hardly be considered plagiarism, and if the work in the new paper is legit there’s no reason to withdraw it.

My suggestion is to submit to the journal where the new paper has been published a “Comment on <published article>” where you point out that the other author’s result is a special case of yours, highlighting the differences. Keep the comment mathematical and *don’t make any accusation of plagiarism, sloppiness or malfeasance*.

---

In the above, I assumed that your paper wasn’t cited in the more recent one from the other author. From a comment below, it seems that you’ve just happened to discover that the authors *did* cite your work.

Then, if this is really the case, *be happy with that and do nothing*.

Comment: So, what action can I take against the authors. What if they cite my paper after I submit the allegation?

Comment: @Charlotte _You shouldn’t take any action against the authors_: overlooking a result is not a fraud, and it’s something that might happen to anyone. As I wrote above, you should not submit any allegation. You simply let a wider audience know that there is _also_ your result, which is a more general one.

Comment: Actually, now I found that they have cited my paper but in a passive way

Comment: @Charlotte What do you mean by "_in a passive way_"? They cited a paper which cited yours?

Comment: @Charlotte Please, don’t start analysing the exact words in which they cited your work. Indeed, we would all love our papers to be cited like “As the wonderful M. Ortolano brilliantly proved in [1]…”, but most of the times we are all cited as in “This problem is also considered in [1-27]”. They _did_ cite your work, and so no further action is needed.

Comment: I too am extremely curious about what makes a citation "passive". Could you explain what you meant, please?

Comment: @MassimoOrtolano I think it's fair to say that "This problem is also considered in [1-27]" would be an *inadequate* citation in the case that the present theorem is truly a special case of that in one of the references, say [16]. It (unintentionally, I grant) misleads the reader by implying that the previous results are related but distinct and the present theorem is novel. The paper should clearly acknowledge the key previous result (OP's) and clarify the actual novelty (in the method or application).

Comment: @A.I.Breveleri; They said "related work on this was done in [1]". They did not say that mine was the more important mone

Answer (score 19):

It is possible that a special case has obvious applications that are not so obvious from the general case. It is possible that the special case had a much simpler proof (which is a good thing to have), or a proof that can be adapted to unrelated situations, while the proof for the general case can't.

Comment: I was also going to comment on proof techniques, and also point out that a simpler proof is not necessarily a requirement either. A merely different proof that ties in different areas of math or relates two previously unrelated concepts can be very publishable even if the result is not novel.

Comment: It can also require a non-trivial amount of work to show that theorem A is a special case of theorem B.

Comment: @quarague Which, seeing as how the OP seems to have done that, might _also_ be a publishable paper.

Answer (score 18):

You assert that "... the editors can see that it [the 2023 paper] is a special case of my paper?" but neither editors nor reviewers normally undertake extensive literature searches to check for overlaps between existing papers and newly submitted manuscripts. They rely, instead, on the general integrity and honesty of most of the authors who are making submissions.

And lest you think that I'm suggesting that the author of the 2023 paper was dishonest, I'm ***not***! It seems to me unlikely that you have discovered a a case of plagiarism; it is much more likely to be a case of having overlooked or not noticed something. It is notoriously difficult to undertake a complete search of the the literature in any domain. Mathematics, because of the structure of [*Mathematical Reviews*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_Reviews), has always seemed particularly difficult.

Even in the unlikely event that the 2023 author used precisely the approach to their proof as you used in yours, it is not uncommon to see papers that focus on even small, but non-obvious special cases of previous work.

Comment: I don't understand the part regarding Mathematical Reviews. Are you suggesting that MR makes literature searches in mathematics *more* difficult?

Comment: @Charlotte: I think a simple and effective solution is to mention this to someone who works at Mathematical Reviews (MR) so that the review of the 2023 paper (if not yet completed) can mention your earlier more general result. I suspect having your paper cited in the MR of the 2023 paper will make your paper more visible than most anything else you can do, since probably most anyone citing the 2023 paper will read over its MR.

Comment: @FedericoPoloni I might not have expressed myself very well; I certainly don't mean to impugn a wonderful resource like MR. What I meant was that I think it is often hard to search for, and then narrow down and identify, all the other papers that might possibly overlap with one's own. I  was primarily trying to highlight *how* the 2023 author might *reasonably* have overlooked the OP's general paper (it actually turns out that the didn't, and that they cited it). Searching often seems to me to be easier in the social sciences ... but perhaps that is reflective my lesser familiarity with MR.

Comment: @DaveLRenfro Please consider making this an answer!

Answer (score 3):

*(edited/extended from a comment made 2 days ago)*

I think a solution that is both simple and quick to carry out, as well as likely being quite effective, is to mention this to [an editor who works at Mathematical Reviews (MR)](http://www.ams.org/publications/math-reviews/edcommandstaff) so that the review of the 2023 paper -- assuming the review is not yet finished -- can mention your earlier more general result. I suspect having your paper cited in the MR review of the 2023 paper will make your paper more visible than most anything else you can do, because people who are interested in the 2023 paper will probably look at its MR review. Looking at the list of MR editor names, I recognize 3 who participate in Stack Exchange -- [1](https://academia.stackexchange.com/users/6038/andr%c3%a9s-e-caicedo) & [2](https://academia.stackexchange.com/users/99964/edward-dunne) & [3](https://mathoverflow.net/users/14493/margaret-friedland). In fact, the first 2 of these participate in Academia SE.